# translate sql to criteriaBuilder

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

```
select * 
from db_object o 
where o.value not like all (array ['%'||chr(32)||chr(32)||'%', '%'||chr(9)||'%', '%'||chr(10)||'%', '%'||chr(13)||'%'])
```

Hello everyone, i dont now how to change sql request  in CriteriaBuilder. I am stuck on this line:

```
where o.value not like all (array ['%'||chr(32)||chr(32)||'%', '%'||chr(9)||'%', '%'||chr(10)||'%', '%'||chr(13)||'%'])
```

I will be very grateful for your help or at least links to interesting material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe to someone helps

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<BaseObject> criteria = builder.createQuery(BaseObject.class);
Root<BaseObject> rootCriteria = criteria.from(BaseObject.class);
List<Predicate> criteriaList = new ArrayList<>();
criteriaList.add(builder.like(rootCriteria.get("value"), "%  %"));
criteriaList.add(builder.like(rootCriteria.get("value"), "%\n%"));
criteriaList.add(builder.like(rootCriteria.get("value"), "%\t%"));
criteriaList.add(builder.like(rootCriteria.get("value"), "%\r%"));
criteria.select(rootCriteria).where(
        builder.or(criteriaList.toArray(new Predicate[criteriaList.size()]))
).orderBy(builder.asc(rootCriteria.get("objectId")));
```